# wp7 c# get control data context

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, user-controls, windows-phone

I have a listbox whose item template is a user control:

```
<ListBox
     x:Name="ChatBox"
     Width="450"
     ItemsSource="{Binding ChatMessage}">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ChatItem DataContext="{Binding ChatMessage}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

in my code behind:

```
messages = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessage>(dbMessages);
ChatBox.ItemsSource = messages;
```

How can I get the bound element, that is, the chat message object from inside the control ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you setting the ItemSource in the code-behind as well? Can you paste your C# code too so we can see.

Answer (score 0):

your **ChatItem** usercontrol is automatically got the its Datacontext to **ChatMessage** Object. it is not required to set it again. and for binding properties of your usercontrol to ChatMessage object properties then your ChatItem properties must be Dependency Properties if you already have them then just bind them to ChatMessage Properties like this.

```
<ListBox
 x:Name="ChatBox"
 Width="450"
 ItemsSource="{Binding ChatMessage}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                <local:ChatItem DataContext="{Binding ChatMessage}" ChatItemDependencyProperty = "{Binding Path=ChatMessageProperty}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

hope it helps you..

Comment: yes I know that, but the problem is that I have a certain value in my ChatMessage, and according to this value I need to set the horizontal alignment property of some panel(left or right). So how I can do that without retrieving  the chat message ?

Comment: what is this "certain value" is it store in some property of your ChatMessage class ? and this "some Panel" is it in your usercontrol(ChatItem) ?

Comment: let's say I have an enum value for message direction( 1: me, 2: him), and according to this value I must set the main panel in CHatItem control left or right. Is that clear enough ?

Comment: ok fine.what you have to done is..first make a depencyproperty of int or string in your chatitem usercontrol and bind it ChatMessage enum value(make sure type(int or string )are same..and then in your chatitem depencyproperty on change event handler put a check what is its value..and on the basis of that set your panel left or right.hope it help you..because the way to communicate between usercontrol is depencyprop. it also make your usercontrol independent

Comment: but the onchange  event handler will not be fired unless I explicitly change this value. onchange event is not fired on initialization which is what I want. We're back now to the initial problem: how can I access my chat message object in order to get to the direction property

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx on this link check how he defining his dependency property and its PropertyChangedCallback in this method you can apply your check.it is called whenever your chatmessage value will be changed..